# Oracle Long Raw Picture

Tags: vb.net, oracle, blob

I have a table named students and have columns named `studentnumber`, `studentphoto`(LONGRAW) and i need to export this longraw as jpeg.How can i do this?
I've searched everywhere but i can't find any solutions.
My Code:

```
Dim ImgWriter As New BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(outsideTxt.Text + "\" + flname))
            Dim ImgBlob(102400) As Byte
            Dim lBytesReturned As Long = 0, lStartIdx As Long = 0
            Dim buffersize As Integer
            buffersize = 4096
            lBytesReturned = x.GetBytes(0, lStartIdx, ImgBlob, 0, buffersize) ' The exception occurs here
            Do While (lBytesReturned = buffersize)
                ImgWriter.Write(ImgBlob)
                ImgWriter.Flush()
                lStartIdx = lStartIdx + buffersize
                lBytesReturned = x.GetBytes(0, lStartIdx, ImgBlob, 0, ImgBlob.Length)

                ImgWriter.Write(ImgBlob)
                ImgWriter.Flush()
                ImgWriter.Close()
            Loop
```

Note: column named photo is returning as null always.
I tried in c# still same.
How can i fix this ?

Comment: hi @Mustibh Upd was this answer helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Long raw datatype is something of the past and it was a mean construct to use. Long raw was for some time the only way to store a binary file in Oracle. You can access it using OCI, preferrably using Pro*C. But using Pro*C introduces an Oracle specific precompiler plus C. The precompiler is known to hard to upgrade over releases.

I would recommend the following approach:

In VB.Net use ODP.Net (if not yet already used) and execute query which casts the long raw to the modern blob, something like:

```
select to_lob(studentphoto) the_photo
from   students
where  studentnumber=250370
```

Then fetch the result of the_photo as you would do also with a varchar2.

If you need more sample, please put the table structure (DDL), an insert with some simple photo (may be just the raw string 'a') and information on the driver used in your question. Good luck!

Comment: Good to hear this fixed it for you.